# If a column contains a substring ( a US state) in a list (of states) change value (to USA) in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I scraped twitter and wanted to sort out the locations of tweets. All data is in a pandas dataframe and I'm using Python 3. I want to do some work on the location column, which looks similar to this:

['location'] 
 
Scottsdale, AZ 
 
London, UK 
 
USA
 
                  (no value)
 
Mission Viejo, CA

etc...

The location data is messy and I want simplify it, starting by classifying the USA as one.

To do this I have a list of state codes: state_list. I am trying to replace the cells containing any state code to USA. I have found how to do this by hard coding a specific state.

```
df.loc[df.location.str.contains('CA'), 'location'] = 'USA'
```

## Above was comparing the entire column value is equal to an item in the state_list

But I'm unable to do it using state_list, I tried using isin(state_list) in place of str.contains('CA')

```
df.loc[df.location.isin(state_list), 'location'] = 'USA'
```

which seems to do nothing. I also attempted a for loop, with various iterations of the code below, but with no avail.

```
for states in state_list:
    if df.loc[df.location.isin(state_list)]:
        df['location'] = 'USA'
```

I feel like there should be a 'simplish' answer to this problem but cant find a solution and have started going round in circles now so have decided to ask. Any help much appreciated and thanks for reading.

The answer is below, thanks for the help guys.

```
pat = r', \b{}\b'.format('|'.join(state_list))
df.loc[df.location.str.contains(pat), 'location'] = 'USA'
```

Although as Håken pointed out this might cause an *'unexpected match for CA in CANADA (for example).' see comments below answer for more info.

Comment: You're comparing that the entire column value is equal to an item in the state_list - presumably you wish to check if it contains a substring of any item? You could probably start with `df.loc[df.location.str.contains('|'.join(state_list)), 'location'] = 'USA'` but I imagine that'd be rather hit and miss unless you isolate more accurately what look like states first...

Comment: Brilliant thanks @JonClements that has worked, so far. I wish I asked earlier now. Yes I did want to compare substring of any item, now I'm going to try and add more to the state_list as they are not all in state codes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close, need `join` all values in `state_list` by `|` for regex `OR` for check substrings by `state_list`:

Thanks @Jon Clements for better solution with `word boundary`:

```
pat = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(state_list))
df.loc[df.location.str.contains(pat, na=False), 'location'] = 'USA'
```

EDIT1:

Thanks @Håken Lid For another suggestion -

> If the state always comes after a comma and a space, you can speed up the regex by making it even more specific.

```
pat = r', ({})$'.format('|'.join(state_list))
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
            location
0     Scottsdale, AZ
1         London, UK
2                USA
3                NaN
4  Mission Viejo, CA

state_list = ['AZ','CA']
pat = r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(state_list))
df.loc[df.location.str.contains(pat, na=False), 'location'] = 'USA'

print (df)
     location
0         USA
1  London, UK
2         USA
3         NaN
4         USA
```

Comment: Slightly better might be: `r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(state_list))`... at least then it'll only consider words...

Comment: @JonClements - Thank you again:)

Comment: If the state always comes after a comma and a space, you can speed up the regex by making it even more specific. `r', ({})$'.format('|'.join(state_list))`

Comment: Brilliant thanks @jezrael and others for edits too. Its nice to know I was close

Comment: For the word boundary to work as expected, you need to use and wrap the states in parenthesis and form a regex grouping:  `r'\b({})\b`. If not, the regex engine will consider the `\b`s to be part of the first and the last option only. So you might get an unexpected match for `CA` in `CANADA` (for example).

Comment: @HåkenLid Thanks, for the very important point. Although I noticed one value was USA-TX and so it didn't change with this method. There are over 30000 entries in the column and so now I am wondering how best to deal with this. I suppose keeping USA-TX and similar is better than changing CANADA to USA but now I'm wondering how to deal with entries such as USA-TX, any thoughts?